# determining which is larger and smaller without selection or "if"statements

Tags: c

I am a very new programmer. This is using C.
  I have to make a program that takes two input integers and squares the smaller one and doubles  the larger one and keeps the integers the same if the two inputs are the same.
  I cannot use relational operators(<,>,<=,>=,or==) or if statements. How would I start this? I understand that I will have to use the modulus but I am failing to see how.
 Any advise would be appreciated!

Comment: is the smaller integer the integer nearer zero or the integer farthest from +infinity? In other words is -5 smaller than 3 or is -7 bigger than 5 or is -5 bigger or smaller than -3

Comment: um. I don't know. so Far i have that the (inputOne + 2) % (inputTwo +1) = modulusOfInput. if that helps

Comment: You should ask yourself "what is the purpose of this task", because I can't come up with any reason you would want to do this. This question is extremely localized.

Comment: I thought that if I could make the answer to this either 1 or 0 then I could use that and apply it to an equation for finding the resulting numbers.

Comment: What you call "selection" operators (<, >) is called *relational operators* in C (along with <=, >= and ==).

Comment: Can you use bitwise operations?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an indirect answer to get you on your way:

```
x = y
X % y == 0
5 % 5 == 0

x < y
x % y == x
3 % 7 == 3
3 % 3 == 0
```

Comment: Nicely done @Esteban just the right amount of hint!

Comment: Err... doesn't `7 % 3` give `1`?

Comment: it's false. 100 % 10 = 0 but 100 != 10.

Comment: Yes @Kerrek SB and mithrop, you are both absolutely correct

Comment: Ok. I am REALLY new at this so I need some more clarity. I have come up with (inputOne + 2) % (inputTwo +1) = modulusOfInput so far and that should help me some how? where would I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this site:
http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax

It shows how you can compare two integers without branches.

Comment: I understand how this works but I am not allowed to use this method. It uses relational operators. But in the quick and dirty section, what does the "&" mean? I have never seen it used like that before.

Comment: The "quick and dirty section" doesn't contain any relational operators. So it's free to use.
Explanation of the & operator:
"The bitwise AND operator (&) compares each bit of the first operand to the corresponding bit of the second operand. If both bits are 1, the corresponding result bit is set to 1. Otherwise, the corresponding result bit is set to 0."

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void no_if(int *p, int *q)
{
int *small, *large;
int diff = *p != *q;

small = *p < *q ? p : q;
large = *p > *q ? p : q;

*large += (diff) ? *large : 0;
*small *= (diff) ? *small : 1;

}

int main(void)
{
int i,j;
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j=0; j < 3; j++) {
                int ix=i;
                int jx=j;
                no_if ( &ix, &jx);
                printf("%d %d -> %d %d\n", i, j, ix, jx );
                }
        }
return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: this uses the comparison / relational operators.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ternary operator

```
  result_a=(!((a-b)&0x8000000))?2*a:((a<b)?a*a:a);
  result_b=(b>a)?2*b:((b<a)?b*b:b);
```

new **UPDATE**:
 or use highest bit of integer:

```
  result_a=((b-a)&0x80000000)*2*a+((a-b)&0x80000000)*a*a*(!!(a-b))+ (!(a-b))*a;      
  result_a=((a-b)&0x80000000)*2*ab+((b-a)&0x80000000)*b*b*(!!(a-b))+ (!(a-b))*b;
```

Comment: that's just a hidden if... probably not what the sneaky prof is looking for

Comment: I am not allowed to use selection like > or< . I have to only use basic operations like +,-,%,/,and *.

Comment: you can look for the highest bit of the result of a-b if it used like unsigned: 1 for minus(a<b), 0 for plus (a>b).

Comment: In a real application a will use IF statement.